# Min-width not working on wrapper

Tags: html, css, width

For some reason i cant get min-width to work. I've currently left it out. If the width on the page is too small, my background doesnt fit anymore (look at the pictures). Im pretty new to creating websites and stuff. My background is pretty much my whole design, if you couldnt notice. So its important that it fits properly at all sizes. Where and how do i write the min-with code? Already tried under #Container (my wrapper). Thanks in advance!

Pictures: [IMGUR LINK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fir9M.jpg)

```
My HTML and CSS: 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>WEBSITE</title>
<style type="text/css">
#Container {
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    border-top-width: 0px;
    border-right-width: 0px;
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-left-style: solid;
    height: 2000px;
    min-width:1000px;
}
#ContentContainer {
    padding: 0px;
    width: 1002px;
    border-top-width: 0px;
    border-right-width: 0px;
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-left-style: solid;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
#Header {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 230px;
}
#Photo {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 232px;
}
#Bilde1 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 347px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border-top-width: 0px;
    border-right-width: 0px;
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-left-style: solid;
    float: left;
}
#Bilde2 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 350px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    float: left;
}
#Bilde3 {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 305px;
}
#MainContent {
    height: 1300px;
    float: left;
    width: 626px;
    padding-left: 9px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
#Search {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    float: right;
    height: 57px;
    width: 360px;
}
#SearchTab {
    margin: 0px;
    float: left;
    height: 42px;
    width: 290px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
#SearchButton {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    float: right;
    width: 60px;
    height: 57px;
    border-top-width: 0px;
    border-right-width: 0px;
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-left-style: solid;
}
#SideBar {
    margin: 0px;
    float: right;
    width: 340px;
    border-top-width: 0px;
    border-right-width: 0px;
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-left-style: solid;
    height: 425px;
    font-family: "Century Gothic";
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
#SideChat {
    float: right;
    height: 480px;
    width: 355px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding-top: 17.5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
#NavBar {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 59px;
    background-image: url(bilder/navbg.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 1100px 59px;

}

body { 
    background-image: url(bg.jpg) ;
    Background-color: #151924;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top center;
    background-attachment: local;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
#sf{
    height:30px;
    width:285px;
    background-color:transparent;
    font-size:18px;
    font-family:"Century Gothic";
    outline:none;
    text-align: center;
}
#sb{
    width:60px;
    height:57px;
}
#Trades{
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
#Salg{
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 5px;

}
#Keys{
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 5px;  
}
#CSGODouble{
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
#Paypal{
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
#Quicksell{
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
#Gratis{
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 5px;  
}
#PC{
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 5px;  
}
#Diskusjon{
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
#Diverse{
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 5px;

</style>
<style>
#rolling-nav {
  font:normal 12px 'Trebuchet MS',Trebuchet,Arial,Sans-Serif;
  color:white;
  text-transform:uppercase;
    /* outline:1px solid; */
    width:100%; /* Fixed width. Measure it manually */
    margin:0px auto;
}

#rolling-nav ul {
  height:59px;
  margin:0px 0px;
  padding:0px 0px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#rolling-nav li {
  float:left;
  display:inline;
  list-style:none;
  margin:0px 0px;
  padding:0px 0px;
}

#rolling-nav a,
#rolling-nav a:before {
  display:block;
  margin:0px 0px;
  padding:0px 30px;
  line-height:59px;
  color:grey;
  text-decoration:none;
  background-color:white;
  background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, white 0%, #F7F7F7 50%, #F5F5F5 50%, #F1F1F1 100%);
  background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top, white 0%, #F7F7F7 50%, #F5F5F5 50%, #F1F1F1 100%);
  background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(top, white 0%, #F7F7F7 50%, #F5F5F5 50%, #F1F1F1 100%);
  background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top, white 0%, #F7F7F7 50%, #F5F5F5 50%, #F1F1F1 100%);
  background-image:linear-gradient(top, white 0%, #F7F7F7 50%, #F5F5F5 50%, #F1F1F1 100%);
  -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  position:relative;
  -webkit-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#rolling-nav a:before {
  content:attr(data-clone);
  position:absolute;
  top:100%;
    right:0px;
  left:0px;
  display:block;
  background-color:#ff6b35;
  background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ff6b35, #C63D0C);
  background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #ff6b35, #C63D0C);
  background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #ff6b35, #C63D0C);
  background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top, #ff6b35, #C63D0C);
  background-image:linear-gradient(top, #ff6b35, #C63D0C);
  color:white;
}

#rolling-nav a:hover {
  margin-top:-59px;
  margin-bottom:1px;
}
#VisMer {
    height: 40px;
    width: 260px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
</style>

</head>

<body> 
<div id="Container">
  <div id="ContentContainer">
    <div id="Header" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="location.href='index.html'"></div>
    <div id="NavBar">
    <nav id="rolling-nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="" data-clone="Hjem">Hjem</a></li>
        <li><a href="regler" data-clone="Regler">Regler</a></li>
        <li><a href="info" data-clone="Info">Info</a></li>
        <li><a href="mm" data-clone="Middleman">Middleman</a></li>
        <li><a href="kontakt" data-clone="Kontakt oss">Kontakt oss</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
    </div>
    <div id="Photo">
      <div id="Bilde1" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="location.href='LINK'"></div>
      <div id="Bilde2" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="location.href='LINK'"></div>
      <div id="Bilde3" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="location.href='LINK'"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="MainContent">
    <div style="border: 0px solid #000; overflow: hidden; margin: 15px auto; max-width: 650px; opacity:1">
<iframe scrolling="yes" src="IFRAME LINK" style="border: 0px none; margin-left: 0px; height: 2575px; margin-top: -1380px; margin-bottom: -222px; width: 650px;">
</iframe>
</div>
    <div id="VisMer" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="location.href='LINK'"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="Search">
    <form id="search" action="SITE LINK SEARCH?" method="get">
        <div id="SearchTab">
<input name="query" type="text" id="sf" style="color: white" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Søk') {this.style.color='#FF6B35   '; this.value=''}" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.style.color='white'; this.value='Søk'}" value="Søk" />
</style>
        </div>
        <div id="SearchButton">
          <input type="image" src="bilder/blank.png" id="sb" alt"Btn">
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
    <div id="SideBar"> <span style="font-size: 30px; color: #ff6b35;">FILTRER</span>
      <div id="Trades" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="location.href='SITE LINK SEARCH?query=[Trade]'"><p style="color: #ff6b35">Trades</p></div>
      <div id="Salg" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="location.href='SITE LINK SEARCH?query=[Salg]'"><p style="color: #ff6b35">Salg</p></div>
      <div id="Keys" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="location.href='SITE LINK SEARCH?query=[Keys]'"><p style="color: #ff6b35">Keys</p></div>
      <div id="CSGODouble" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="location.href='SITE LINK SEARCH?query=[CSGODouble]'"><p style="color: #ff6b35">CSGODouble</p></div>
      <div id="Paypal" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="location.href='SITE LINK SEARCH?query=[PayPal]'"><p style="color: #ff6b35">PayPal</p></div>
      <div id="Quicksell" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="location.href='SITE LINK SEARCH?query=[Quicksell]'"><p style="color: #ff6b35">Quicksell</p></div>
      <div id="Gratis" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="location.href='SITE LINK SEARCH?query=[Gratis]'"><p style="color: #ff6b35">Gratis</p></div>
      <div id="PC" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="location.href='SITE LINK SEARCH?query=[PC]'"><p style="color: #ff6b35">Price Check</p></div>
      <div id="Diskusjon" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="location.href='SITE'"><p style="color: #ff6b35">Diskusjon</p></div>
      <div id="Diverse" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="location.href='SITE'"><p style="color: #ff6b35">Diverse</p></div>

    </div>
    <div id="SideChat">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="LINK WITH CHAT BOX SCRIPT"></script></div>
  </div>
  <p>&nbsp; </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

PS: I DON'T want my site to be responsive. I want it to be centered, but not change otherwies when with is changing.

Comment: Wow. Look here [CSS min-width Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-width.asp), and here [Cascading Order](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp).

Comment: I tried putting in min-width but i cant get it to work. I tried both on body and on the wrapper/container. I also tried putting all the css code to a style, and then adding the min-width, but still no luck

Answer (score 0):

remove margins from body.
css:
body {margin:0}

if you want to put an background image,
you could use background-size instead with "cover" option.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Comment: Tried changing it and putting background-size to cover, but i still couldnt get min-width to work and and now the background also became smaller. Still cant seem to get min-width to work, so everything stops moving when its under 500px

Comment: Why you use ID? You should use classes. You are probably using some kind of html generator. You could try to use bootstrap grid (getbootstrap.com).

Comment: im using dreamweaver, not 100% sure what you mean

Comment: ID is #element it is mainly for identify exact element in html mostly for js purposes. You can only have one ID with each name. .class is element which define style and you can have multiple elements with the same name on single page.

Comment: By the way, I DON'T want my site to be responsive. I want it to be centered, but not change otherwies when with is changing.

Comment: I removed all the "%" in the with and changed it to pixels, but still i get the same problem. I just want it to be static

Comment: #Diverse tag is not closed. add } after class definition

Comment: alt"Btn"> - here "=" is missing

Comment: <div id="SearchTab"> is closed by </style> tag and should be closed by </div>

Comment: <div id="Search">
    <form id="search"
duplicated ID - it is forbidden I've wrote before that you can't have ID with the same class. Does Dreamweaver doesn't show errors?

Comment: I've corrected the code a bit and pasted as a new answer, please try it.

Answer (score 0):

you have a lot of html errors https://validator.w3.org/check

tidy code from w3.org

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta name="generator" content="HTML Tidy for Linux (vers 25 March 2009), see www.w3.org" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>WEBSITE</title>

<style type="text/css">
/*<![CDATA[*/
#Container {
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    border-top-width: 0px;
    border-right-width: 0px;
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-left-style: solid;
    height: 2000px;
    min-width:1000px;
}
#ContentContainer {
    padding: 0px;
    width: 1002px;
    border-top-width: 0px;
    border-right-width: 0px;
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-left-style: solid;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
#Header {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 230px;
}
#Photo {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 232px;
}
#Bilde1 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 347px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border-top-width: 0px;
    border-right-width: 0px;
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-left-style: solid;
    float: left;
}
#Bilde2 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 350px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    float: left;
}
#Bilde3 {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 305px;
}
#MainContent {
    height: 1300px;
    float: left;
    width: 626px;
    padding-left: 9px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
#Search {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    float: right;
    height: 57px;
    width: 360px;
}
#SearchTab {
    margin: 0px;
    float: left;
    height: 42px;
    width: 290px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
#SearchButton {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    float: right;
    width: 60px;
    height: 57px;
    border-top-width: 0px;
    border-right-width: 0px;
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-left-style: solid;
}
#SideBar {
    margin: 0px;
    float: right;
    width: 340px;
    border-top-width: 0px;
    border-right-width: 0px;
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-left-style: solid;
    height: 425px;
    font-family: "Century Gothic";
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
#SideChat {
    float: right;
    height: 480px;
    width: 355px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding-top: 17.5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
#NavBar {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 59px;
    background-image: url(bilder/navbg.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 1100px 59px;

}

body { 
   margin:0 auto; 
   background-image: url(bg.jpg) ;
    Background-color: #151924;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top center;
    background-attachment: local;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
#sf{
    height:30px;
    width:285px;
    background-color:transparent;
    font-size:18px;
    font-family:"Century Gothic";
    outline:none;
    text-align: center;
}
#sb{
    width:60px;
    height:57px;
}
#Trades{
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
#Salg{
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 5px;

}
#Keys{
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 5px;  
}
#CSGODouble{
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
#Paypal{
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
#Quicksell{
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
#Gratis{
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 5px;  
}
#PC{
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 5px;  
}
#Diskusjon{
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
#Diverse{
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 5px;

/*]]>*/
</style>

<style type="text/css">
/*<![CDATA[*/
#rolling-nav {
  font:normal 12px 'Trebuchet MS',Trebuchet,Arial,Sans-Serif;
  color:white;
  text-transform:uppercase;
    /* outline:1px solid; */
    width:100%; /* Fixed width. Measure it manually */
    margin:0px auto;
}

#rolling-nav ul {
  height:59px;
  margin:0px 0px;
  padding:0px 0px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#rolling-nav li {
  float:left;
  display:inline;
  list-style:none;
  margin:0px 0px;
  padding:0px 0px;
}

#rolling-nav a,
#rolling-nav a:before {
  display:block;
  margin:0px 0px;
  padding:0px 30px;
  line-height:59px;
  color:grey;
  text-decoration:none;
  background-color:white;
  background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, white 0%, #F7F7F7 50%, #F5F5F5 50%, #F1F1F1 100%);
  background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top, white 0%, #F7F7F7 50%, #F5F5F5 50%, #F1F1F1 100%);
  background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(top, white 0%, #F7F7F7 50%, #F5F5F5 50%, #F1F1F1 100%);
  background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top, white 0%, #F7F7F7 50%, #F5F5F5 50%, #F1F1F1 100%);
  background-image:linear-gradient(top, white 0%, #F7F7F7 50%, #F5F5F5 50%, #F1F1F1 100%);
  -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  position:relative;
  -webkit-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#rolling-nav a:before {
  content:attr(data-clone);
  position:absolute;
  top:100%;
    right:0px;
  left:0px;
  display:block;
  background-color:#ff6b35;
  background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ff6b35, #C63D0C);
  background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #ff6b35, #C63D0C);
  background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #ff6b35, #C63D0C);
  background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top, #ff6b35, #C63D0C);
  background-image:linear-gradient(top, #ff6b35, #C63D0C);
  color:white;
}

#rolling-nav a:hover {
  margin-top:-59px;
  margin-bottom:1px;
}
#VisMer {
    height: 40px;
    width: 260px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
/*]]>*/
</style>

<style type="text/css">
/*<![CDATA[*/
 p.c6 {color: #ff6b35}
 span.c5 {font-size: 30px; color: #ff6b35;}
 input.c4 {color: white}
 div.c3 {border: 0px solid #000; overflow: hidden; margin: 15px auto; max-width: 650px; opacity:1}
 iframe.c2 {border: 0px none; margin-left: 0px; height: 2575px; margin-top: -1380px; margin-bottom: -222px; width: 650px;}
 div.c1 {cursor: pointer;}
/*]]>*/
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="Container">
<div id="ContentContainer">
<div id="Header" class="c1" onclick="location.href='index.html'"></div>
<div id="NavBar">
<ul>
<li><a href="">Hjem</a></li>
<li><a href="regler">Regler</a></li>
<li><a href="info">Info</a></li>
<li><a href="mm">Middleman</a></li>
<li><a href="kontakt">Kontakt oss</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="Photo">
<div id="Bilde1" class="c1" onclick="location.href='LINK'"></div>
<div id="Bilde2" class="c1" onclick="location.href='LINK'"></div>
<div id="Bilde3" class="c1" onclick="location.href='LINK'"></div>
</div>
<div id="MainContent">
<div class="c3"><iframe scrolling="yes" src="IFRAME%20LINK" class="c2"></iframe></div>
<div id="VisMer" class="c1" onclick="location.href='LINK'"></div>
</div>
<div id="Search">
<form id="search" action="SITE%20LINK%20SEARCH?" method="get" name="search">
<div id="SearchTab"><input name="query" type="text" id="sf" class="c4" onfocus="if (this.value == 'S�k') {this.style.color='#FF6B35 '; this.value=''}" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.style.color='white'; this.value='S�k'}" value="S�k" /></div>
<div id="SearchButton"><input type="image" src="bilder/blank.png" id="sb" /></div>
</form>
</div>
<div id="SideBar"><span class="c5">FILTRER</span>
<div id="Trades" class="c1" onclick="location.href='SITE LINK SEARCH?query=[Trade]'">
<p class="c6">Trades</p>
</div>
<div id="Salg" class="c1" onclick="location.href='SITE LINK SEARCH?query=[Salg]'">
<p class="c6">Salg</p>
</div>
<div id="Keys" class="c1" onclick="location.href='SITE LINK SEARCH?query=[Keys]'">
<p class="c6">Keys</p>
</div>
<div id="CSGODouble" class="c1" onclick="location.href='SITE LINK SEARCH?query=[CSGODouble]'">
<p class="c6">CSGODouble</p>
</div>
<div id="Paypal" class="c1" onclick="location.href='SITE LINK SEARCH?query=[PayPal]'">
<p class="c6">PayPal</p>
</div>
<div id="Quicksell" class="c1" onclick="location.href='SITE LINK SEARCH?query=[Quicksell]'">
<p class="c6">Quicksell</p>
</div>
<div id="Gratis" class="c1" onclick="location.href='SITE LINK SEARCH?query=[Gratis]'">
<p class="c6">Gratis</p>
</div>
<div id="PC" class="c1" onclick="location.href='SITE LINK SEARCH?query=[PC]'">
<p class="c6">Price Check</p>
</div>
<div id="Diskusjon" class="c1" onclick="location.href='SITE'">
<p class="c6">Diskusjon</p>
</div>
<div id="Diverse" class="c1" onclick="location.href='SITE'">
<p class="c6">Diverse</p>
</div>
</div>
<div id="SideChat"><script type="text/javascript" src="LINK%20WITH%20CHAT%20BOX%20SCRIPT">
</script></div>
</div>
<p> </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! will this fix the with?

Comment: without seeing the actual site it's hard to say, start with putting that in the css sheet and save it as styles2.css and then duplicate your index page and save it as index2.html and test it. Making the duplicate pages allows you to save the originals and not mess with them

Comment: I just realized that all of your css in in the html page. Do this. Add this line between the head tags '<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head> ' and copy ALL of your css into notepad, then go copy the media queries from this link and add it all [link]https://gist.github.com/needim/d15fdc2ac133d8078f7c and hit save as styles.css. Upload that to the root drive. On the html page delete all of the css code. That last bit of code will make your page responsive.

Comment: I did like you said and moved all the css code into a styles.css. Then i added the code from the link u sent, but that still didnt help my problem. Min width is not working. I want to make the page stop changing when it becomes less than for example 500px. Also when i moved all the css code over to the style, the navbar working. But it doesnt matter that much. The important thing is that i find out how to get min-width working. It cant be that hard. Why isnt just putting min-width: 500px; working?

Comment: BTW, I DON'T want my site to be responsive. I want it to be centered, but not change otherwies when with is changing.

Comment: I removed all the "%" in the with and changed it to pixels, but still i get the same problem. I just want it to be static

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code with critic errors corrected - try if it helps,
i can't see the images so I'm not sure if it resolves your problem.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <title>WEBSITE</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    #Container {
      padding: 0px;
      width: 100%;
      border-top-width: 0px;
      border-right-width: 0px;
      border-bottom-width: 0px;
      border-left-width: 0px;
      border-top-style: solid;
      border-right-style: solid;
      border-bottom-style: solid;
      border-left-style: solid;
      height: 2000px;
      min-width: 1000px;
    }

    #ContentContainer {
      padding: 0px;
      width: 1002px;
      border-top-width: 0px;
      border-right-width: 0px;
      border-bottom-width: 0px;
      border-left-width: 0px;
      border-top-style: solid;
      border-right-style: solid;
      border-bottom-style: solid;
      border-left-style: solid;
      position: relative;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-left: auto;
    }

    #Header {
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      height: 230px;
    }

    #Photo {
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      height: 232px;
    }

    #Bilde1 {
      height: 100%;
      width: 347px;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      border-top-width: 0px;
      border-right-width: 0px;
      border-bottom-width: 0px;
      border-left-width: 0px;
      border-top-style: solid;
      border-right-style: solid;
      border-bottom-style: solid;
      border-left-style: solid;
      float: left;
    }

    #Bilde2 {
      height: 100%;
      width: 350px;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      float: left;
    }

    #Bilde3 {
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      float: left;
      height: 100%;
      width: 305px;
    }

    #MainContent {
      height: 1300px;
      float: left;
      width: 626px;
      padding-left: 9px;
      padding-right: 5px;
    }

    #Search {
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      float: right;
      height: 57px;
      width: 360px;
    }

    #SearchTab {
      margin: 0px;
      float: left;
      height: 42px;
      width: 290px;
      padding-top: 15px;
      padding-right: 0px;
      padding-bottom: 0px;
      padding-left: 10px;
    }

    #SearchButton {
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      float: right;
      width: 60px;
      height: 57px;
      border-top-width: 0px;
      border-right-width: 0px;
      border-bottom-width: 0px;
      border-left-width: 0px;
      border-top-style: solid;
      border-right-style: solid;
      border-bottom-style: solid;
      border-left-style: solid;
    }

    #SideBar {
      margin: 0px;
      float: right;
      width: 340px;
      border-top-width: 0px;
      border-right-width: 0px;
      border-bottom-width: 0px;
      border-left-width: 0px;
      border-top-style: solid;
      border-right-style: solid;
      border-bottom-style: solid;
      border-left-style: solid;
      height: 425px;
      font-family: "Century Gothic";
      padding-top: 20px;
      padding-right: 0px;
      padding-bottom: 0px;
      padding-left: 20px;
    }

    #SideChat {
      float: right;
      height: 480px;
      width: 355px;
      margin: 0px;
      padding-top: 17.5px;
      padding-right: 5px;
      padding-bottom: 0px;
      padding-left: 0px;
    }

    #NavBar {
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      height: 59px;
      background-image: url(bilder/navbg.jpg);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: 1100px 59px;

    }

    body {
      background-image: url(bg.jpg);
      Background-color: #151924;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: top center;
      background-attachment: local;
      overflow-x: hidden;
    }

    #sf {
      height: 30px;
      width: 285px;
      background-color: transparent;
      font-size: 18px;
      font-family: "Century Gothic";
      outline: none;
      text-align: center;
    }

    #sb {
      width: 60px;
      height: 57px;
    }

    #Trades {
      background-color: #e4e4e4;
      padding-left: 10px;
      margin-right: 5px;
    }

    #Salg {
      background-color: #e4e4e4;
      padding-left: 10px;
      margin-right: 5px;

    }

    #Keys {
      background-color: #e4e4e4;
      padding-left: 10px;
      margin-right: 5px;
    }

    #CSGODouble {
      background-color: #e4e4e4;
      padding-left: 10px;
      margin-right: 5px;
    }

    #Paypal {
      background-color: #e4e4e4;
      padding-left: 10px;
      margin-right: 5px;
    }

    #Quicksell {
      background-color: #e4e4e4;
      padding-left: 10px;
      margin-right: 5px;
    }

    #Gratis {
      background-color: #e4e4e4;
      padding-left: 10px;
      margin-right: 5px;
    }

    #PC {
      background-color: #e4e4e4;
      padding-left: 10px;
      margin-right: 5px;
    }

    #Diskusjon {
      background-color: #e4e4e4;
      padding-left: 10px;
      margin-right: 5px;
    }

    #Diverse {
      background-color: #e4e4e4;
      padding-left: 10px;
      margin-right: 5px;
    }
  </style>
  <style>
    #rolling-nav {
      font: normal 12px 'Trebuchet MS', Trebuchet, Arial, Sans-Serif;
      color: white;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      /* outline:1px solid; */
      width: 100%; /* Fixed width. Measure it manually */
      margin: 0px auto;
    }

    #rolling-nav ul {
      height: 59px;
      margin: 0px 0px;
      padding: 0px 0px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    #rolling-nav li {
      float: left;
      display: inline;
      list-style: none;
      margin: 0px 0px;
      padding: 0px 0px;
    }

    #rolling-nav a,
    #rolling-nav a:before {
      display: block;
      margin: 0px 0px;
      padding: 0px 30px;
      line-height: 59px;
      color: grey;
      text-decoration: none;
      background-color: white;
      background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, white 0%, #F7F7F7 50%, #F5F5F5 50%, #F1F1F1 100%);
      background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, white 0%, #F7F7F7 50%, #F5F5F5 50%, #F1F1F1 100%);
      background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, white 0%, #F7F7F7 50%, #F5F5F5 50%, #F1F1F1 100%);
      background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, white 0%, #F7F7F7 50%, #F5F5F5 50%, #F1F1F1 100%);
      background-image: linear-gradient(top, white 0%, #F7F7F7 50%, #F5F5F5 50%, #F1F1F1 100%);
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
      -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
      box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
      position: relative;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
      -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
      -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
      transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    }

    #rolling-nav a:before {
      content: attr(data-clone);
      position: absolute;
      top: 100%;
      right: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      display: block;
      background-color: #ff6b35;
      background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ff6b35, #C63D0C);
      background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ff6b35, #C63D0C);
      background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ff6b35, #C63D0C);
      background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ff6b35, #C63D0C);
      background-image: linear-gradient(top, #ff6b35, #C63D0C);
      color: white;
    }

    #rolling-nav a:hover {
      margin-top: -59px;
      margin-bottom: 1px;
    }

    #VisMer {
      height: 40px;
      width: 260px;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
<div id="Container">
  <div id="ContentContainer">
    <div id="Header" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="location.href='index.html'"></div>
    <div id="NavBar">
      <nav id="rolling-nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="" data-clone="Hjem">Hjem</a></li>
          <li><a href="regler" data-clone="Regler">Regler</a></li>
          <li><a href="info" data-clone="Info">Info</a></li>
          <li><a href="mm" data-clone="Middleman">Middleman</a></li>
          <li><a href="kontakt" data-clone="Kontakt oss">Kontakt oss</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div id="Photo">
      <div id="Bilde1" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="location.href='LINK'"></div>
      <div id="Bilde2" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="location.href='LINK'"></div>
      <div id="Bilde3" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="location.href='LINK'"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="MainContent">
      <div style="border: 0px solid #000; overflow: hidden; margin: 15px auto; max-width: 650px; opacity:1">
        <iframe scrolling="yes" src="IFRAME LINK"
                style="border: 0px none; margin-left: 0px; height: 2575px; margin-top: -1380px; margin-bottom: -222px; width: 650px;">
        </iframe>
      </div>
      <div id="VisMer" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="location.href='LINK'"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="Search">
      <form id="search2" action="SITE LINK SEARCH?" method="get">
        <div id="SearchTab">
          <input name="query" type="text" id="sf" style="color: white"
                 onfocus="if (this.value == 'Søk') {this.style.color='#FF6B35   '; this.value=''}"
                 onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.style.color='white'; this.value='Søk'}" value="Søk"/>


          <div id="SearchButton">
            <input type="image" src="bilder/blank.png" id="sb" alt="Btn">
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
      <div id="SideBar"><span style="font-size: 30px; color: #ff6b35;">FILTRER</span>
        <div id="Trades" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="location.href='SITE LINK SEARCH?query=[Trade]'"><p
            style="color: #ff6b35">Trades</p></div>
        <div id="Salg" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="location.href='SITE LINK SEARCH?query=[Salg]'"><p
            style="color: #ff6b35">Salg</p></div>
        <div id="Keys" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="location.href='SITE LINK SEARCH?query=[Keys]'"><p
            style="color: #ff6b35">Keys</p></div>
        <div id="CSGODouble" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="location.href='SITE LINK SEARCH?query=[CSGODouble]'"><p
            style="color: #ff6b35">CSGODouble</p></div>
        <div id="Paypal" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="location.href='SITE LINK SEARCH?query=[PayPal]'"><p
            style="color: #ff6b35">PayPal</p></div>
        <div id="Quicksell" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="location.href='SITE LINK SEARCH?query=[Quicksell]'"><p
            style="color: #ff6b35">Quicksell</p></div>
        <div id="Gratis" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="location.href='SITE LINK SEARCH?query=[Gratis]'"><p
            style="color: #ff6b35">Gratis</p></div>
        <div id="PC" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="location.href='SITE LINK SEARCH?query=[PC]'"><p
            style="color: #ff6b35">Price Check</p></div>
        <div id="Diskusjon" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="location.href='SITE'"><p style="color: #ff6b35">
          Diskusjon</p></div>
        <div id="Diverse" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="location.href='SITE'"><p style="color: #ff6b35">Diverse</p>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div id="SideChat">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="LINK WITH CHAT BOX SCRIPT"></script>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>&nbsp; </p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No it didnt solve my problem :/ but thanks for trying

Comment: I would like to help you, but I can't reproduce the problem. Could you provide example with images which gives exact your problem?

Comment: Its the same problem i had earlier. Here are some screenshots. http://imgur.com/a/rPmao I dont want anything to change when the width becomes less than for example 700px.

Comment: check if the iframe content does the problem. Remove the content and check it.

Comment: I removed the iframe, but its still happening. I dont understand at all why :S

Comment: can you put it somewhere in the Internet? I can't see the problem other than in screens.